# Очередь. Проблема с удалением первого элемента

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct List
{
    int a;
    List* next;
};
void Print(List* c)
{
    List* print = c;

    while (print)
    {
        cout << print->a << "->";
        print = print->next;
    }

    cout << "NULL" << endl;
}
void Remove(List** begin)
{
    List* t = new List;

    while (*begin != NULL)
    {
        t = *begin;
        *begin = t->next;
    }

    return;
}
void Add_end(List* end)
{
    List* t = new List;
    t->a = NULL;
    t->next = NULL;
    cin >> t->a;
    end->next = t;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    List* begin = new List;
    begin->a = NULL;
    begin->next = NULL;
    cout << "Input the length of the queue" << endl;
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    cout << "Input the queue" << endl;
    cin >> begin->a;
    List* end = begin;

    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
    {
        end->next = new List;
        end = end->next;
        cin >> end->a;
        end->next = NULL;
    }

    Print(begin);
    int ind = 100;
    cout << "If you want to end the program enter '0'" << endl;

    while (ind != 0)
    {
        cout << "If you want to add element enter '1' and if you want to delete     enter '2'"
             << endl;
        cin >> ind;

        if (ind == 1)
        {
            Add_end(end);
            Print(begin);
        }

        if (ind == 2)
        {
            Remove(&begin);
            Print(begin);
        }
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу удалить первый элемент, подозреваю что надо использовать delete но не уверен. Подскажите как доработать функцию Remove.

Comment: Интересно бы послушать вашу версию, что вы вообще делаете в функции `Remove`... Просто для интереса - как вы себе представляете, что в ней происходит...

Comment: для начала посмотрите, где вам нужно поставить `delete`

Comment: В функции Remove здесь я началу присваиваю  адресс следующего элемента. Я не знаю как это сделать правильно, поэтому и прошу помощи, не могли бы вы написать как должна выглядеть эта фунция????

Comment: Так а что в вашей функции `Remove` делает цикл? Цикл выполняет повторяющиеся действия. Что за действие вы собрались *повторять*?

Comment: ой спасибо, я натупил, я весь список так унижтожал

Comment: а вообще, зря вы элемент списка назвали списком.

Comment: Интересно, а почему в виде методов?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct List
{
    int a;
    List* next;
    List(int a = 0):a(a),next(nullptr){}
};

void Print(List* c)
{
    List* print = c;

    while (print)
    {
        cout << print->a << "->";
        print = print->next;
    }

    cout << "NULL" << endl;
}

void Remove(List*&begin)
{
    if (begin)
    {
        List * cur = begin->next;
        delete begin;
        begin = cur;
    }
}

void Add_end(List*&begin, int n)
{
    if (begin == nullptr)
    {
        begin = new List(n);
    }
    else
    {
        List * cur = begin;
        for(; cur->next; cur = cur->next);
        cur->next = new List(n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    List *begin = 0;
    cout << "Input the length of the queue" << endl;
    Print(begin);

    int ind = 100;
    cout << "If you want to end the program enter '0'" << endl;
    while (ind != 0)
    {
        cout << "If you want to add element enter '1' and if you want to delete     enter '2'"
             << endl;
        cin >> ind;
        if (ind == 1)
        {
            cout << "Value to add: ";
            int n;
            cin >> n;
            Add_end(begin,n);
            Print(begin);
        }
        if (ind == 2)
        {
            Remove(begin);
            Print(begin);
        }
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```